# Forcing all requests except /feed to HTTPS using mod_rewrite and wordpress

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

New to Apache VirtualHosts and Mod_Rewrite, but I get the idea.

I have read several threads here and followed them all, tried them and I am still not getting the results I am searching for.

My goal:

- Force all incoming requests to be HTTPS **except** feeds coming into /feed

The point of this is for feedburner so we can serve up our webpages via https but feedburner will still be able to handle our native feed coming out from wordpress.

Here is the current rewrite rule I am trying:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/feed
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteLog /xxxx/xxxx/logs/rewrite_log
RewriteLogLevel 3

<Directory />
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

The above is forcing me back to the homepage if i type in www.mydomain.net/feed and the url ends up www.mydomain.net. It is forcing everything to HTTPS though as I would expect.

I can get the **opposite** to work (force HTTPS on /feed and HTTP on anything else) with the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/feed
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteLog /xxx/xxx/logs/rewrite_log
RewriteLogLevel 3

<Directory />
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

But when I try to reverse that statement like this it does not work and forces https to /feed.

Is there something wordpress is doing that is breaking my rules? not 100% sure what the Directory/ block is doing but that was put in by wordpress I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

#check if https is off, force it on for all except /feed
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/feed [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#check if https is on, turn off for /feed
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/feed/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/feed/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteLog /xxx/xxx/logs/rewrite_log
RewriteLogLevel 3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/server-status$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```